# Call Web Reference using ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, soap, wsdl

In visual Studio I've added a WSDL web reference which loads a variety of "methods" for calling a SOAP api. I have a blank aspx page. How do I call these methods loaded by the web reference? I've called the web reference mywsdl.

Here's my code so far:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="WebApplication1" %>
<%
End Sub
Private Sub Call_Web_Service_Method()
    Dim output
    Dim CallWebService As New ServerName.mywsdl()
    Dim sGetValue As String = CallWebService.GetSomeValue()
    output = sGetValue
End Sub
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%=output%>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't use a Service Reference? Web References are part of the legacy ASMX web service technology, and should not be used for new development.

Comment: How do you do a service reference with a wsdl?

Comment: Huh? That's how you _do_ service references! Just use "Add Service Reference", and enter the URL to the WSDL.

Comment: I get that. That's the easy part. How do you call them in an aspx page?

Comment: I'll tell you on the condition that you help me out. Please see http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/, then tell me what part you didn't get right away. It could be something small that's keeping me from communicating to you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the web service as a reference at the top of your code behind web page, instantiate a new instance of it where you need it and use it.  The methods should already be exposed as you've successfully imported the .asmx I believe, however if you're not getting data back it might require authentication.

```
using mywsdl;

mywsdl my = new mywsdl();
```

or

```
Imports mywsdl

Dim my = new mywsdl()
```

Comment: When using these two methods I get a lot of syntax errors or not defined errors. I put them right at the top of the aspx page. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I figured out the syntax problem. Once I declare it with Dim... how do I call a method/function like GetUser()?

Comment: Would you mind looking at http://pastebin.com/5Tqa8HCm and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the imports statement goes at the very top of your code, the variable declaration, where you intend to use the methods of the service, like in page load for example.  You'd call my.GetUser() ...if it's exposed via intellisense is a good way to tell that everything's working.  Also, my web filter blocks pastebin completely, post your code in your original post maybe?

Comment: I got everything working except I get Servername.mywsdl() not defined, how do I define it?